# Which string identifiers for field types do exist?

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes

There are several enum classes containing constants such as the `SectionType` class which I can use to create sections:

```
//  …
$section = new SectionModel();
$section->type = SectionType::Single;
//  …
```

But what about creating fields? Currently I create fields like so:

```
//  …
$field = new FieldModel();
$field->type = 'PlainText';
//  …
```

Is there any enum class containing valid identifiers I could use to create a field? Like in the following way?

```
//  …
$field = new FieldModel();
$field->type = FieldType::PlainText;     // Does something like this exist?
//  …
```

I can't find such a class or any other listing of existing field types, where do I?

Unfortunately, a list of string identifiers is missing on the guide for [plugin development and field types](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/field-types). The [list of field types](https://craftcms.com/docs/fields#field-types) only tells me which field types exist but not what identifiers they have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if any enum exists (couldn't find it in source), but you could have a look at the contents of the `craft/app/fieldtypes` folder (and ignore BaseFieldtypes, DataModels and interfaces) to find the identifiers:

- UsersFieldType.php
- TagsFieldType.php
- TableFieldType.php
- RichTextFieldType.php
- RadioButtonsFieldType.php
- PositionSelectFieldType.php
- PlainTextFieldType.php
- NumberFieldType.php
- MultiSelectFieldType.php
- MatrixFieldType.php
- LightswitchFieldType.php
- EntriesFieldType.php
- DropdownFieldType.php
- DateFieldType.php
- ColorFieldType.php
- CheckboxesFieldType.php
- CategoriesFieldType.php
- AssetsFieldType.php

String identifiers correspond to the file names (without "FieldType.php", obviously).

Comment: Ah! Seems obvious, yeah… to me it wasn't. I already knew where the field type implementations are located but I didn't see the relation between file name and string identifier. Yep, pretty shortsighted. ;) Shame on me and thanks to you. :) … But still, I hoped there would have been an enum I could use (because of easiness with auto-complete). Nevertheless, get my upvote. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[Paul is correct](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15333/57), but probably worth adding if you want the full list of "enums" Craft has available you can look at [`craft.app.enums`](https://craftcms.com/classreference#craft.app.enums) in the class reference.